# Suddenly unable to send SMS from macOS (names marked RED)

Tags: messages, sms

I've used "Forward Text Messages" for years to send SMS from macOS. Since last week, names of "SMS people" are marked RED in Messages, and I can't send SMS from macOS anymore.

I've updated to the latest iOS and macOS, logged out and in of iCloud on both devices, and flicked "Forward Text Messages" in Settings off and on several times, to no avail.

My only lead is that when flicking the setting, I'm supposed to be asked to enter a code (on the Mac, I think), but this does not happen. Apple Store had no idea and I've found no help on the Web.

Clicking on the red name shows this context menu:

```
✔︎ (number)                        iMessage  (Ghosted)
  (number) is not registered with iMessage  (Ghosted)
Remove (name) from chat
Show contact card
```

Also, the message field at the bottom shows "iMessage", where it said "Text message" before.

SMS sent from iOS are added to messages on macOS. So it works that way, but not from macOS to iOS (because Messages does not seem to know about SMS, only iMessage.)

**NEW:** Turned "Forward Text Messages" off, turned off both Mac and iPhone, turned both on, and turned "Forward Text Messages" on. I get no question about entering a code, and still RED names.

Comment: Try clicking one of the red headers & re-assigning the number. I've had that happen before, when something 'just got confused'

Comment: What do you mean by "re-assigning the number"? It has happened for all my "SMS contacts" (people without iPhones), so it's not linked to a specific contact.

Comment: so... what did you see when you clicked one of the headers?

Comment: See updated posting.

Comment: hmm... I'm sure I had perhaps a 3rd entry when it happened to me... either I had something I *could* select instead which made it re-think, or I opened the contact card [it's too long ago for me to recall exactly, sorry]

Comment: Have you tried the usual of rebooting both iPhone and Mac after disabling **Text Message Forwarding**? Hopefully that will cause “something” to update, and prompt you for a new code after re-enabling **Text Message Forwarding**. Also, dumb question but is **Send as SMS** enabled on your iPhone? I don’t know if that would make any difference.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue just began this weekend. I am wondering if it has anything to do with any updated that MacOS did to my machine on the 7th.

Comment: Tried rebooting. The problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your iPhone, do you have an email address checked under settings>Messages>"send & receive"?

for some reason, it only works when I have an email address checked which was not the case before.  They must have changed something on their end to require the use of an email.

Comment: You're right. This resolved the issue. But why the @$!# have they changed this? Having multiple addresses for iMessage is guaranteed to create a mess (at least it did before!)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! This worked for me. Had to had email.  Went back to just phone number and text only contacts turned red again and would've send messages.  Could receive though.  Re-added email and Contacts turned green again.  They must have changed something on their end.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now, and user233886 gave me the idea to try something on my iPhone. I went to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive, unchecked all my email addresses, waited a few seconds, then checked the email addresses again.

My Mac immediately asked if I wanted to allow something, and I accepted. After about 30 seconds, the names were no longer red in the Mac Messages app.

Comment: This worked for me. The additional messages were from your other devices that are sharing your iMessage texts, like my MacBook, my iPhone, and my iPad. Also, clarify, I did not uncheck the phone number in Settings>Messages>Send&Recv. Only the eMail addresses. Then waited a few seconds for the devices to all respond. In fact, in my case it cleaned itself up after some waiting without rechecking the eMails. I did that later, once the red names were back to normal in iMessage (on MacBook)